# Fork size and suitability

Tags: road-bike, fork

I'm looking to replace the front fork on my 2007 Specialized Roubaix Comp. Here are the Specialized specs:

- Fork Length (full) = 375mm
- Offset =47mm
- Head Tube Length = 140mm

Using a standard 700C wheel I want to make sure the brakes align with the rim.
Having a difficult time finding aftermarket carbon forks that are exactly 375mm in length.

How much can I vary from the 375mm length?

Comment: you mention a variance in what you have found. What range are you finding?  (edit your question to add that info please).

Comment: You know a new carbon fibre fork would have an over-length steerer tube intended to be cut down on installation, right ?   A used fork is likely already cut to length.

Answer (score 1):

So we're discussing the same thing, here are the specs of the fork on an '07 Roubaix. Specialized FACT carbon with Zertz inserts, rim brake compatible, straight 1⅛" steer tube, 100mm spaced open dropouts, max tire size is 700c x 28mm width. When listed the spec for fork rake is 45 to 47mm and a 370mm axle to crown length. [Something like this listing on eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/186193049560?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0&ssspo=2N00LFHIS0G&sssrc=4429486&ssuid=H4hCb3nAQpy&var=&widget_ver=artemis&media=COPY).
*This is not an endorsement of eBay, but merely represents one of many links one may find in a Google search of "2007 Specialized Roubaix fork."

It was difficult to find a listing with axle to crown or even the rake listed in many postings. Even the Specialized website missed a few details of the fork. [Specs for 2007 Specialized Roubaix Comp](https://www.specialized.com/sk/en/roubaix-comp-triple/p/21364?color=23264-21364). Your size must be the 52cm which has a 145mm length head tube.  The size and certainly the rake of the fork will remain consistent through the sizes except for possibly at the extremes (XS and XL).

This [eBay listing for a Spesh Roubaix fork](https://www.ebay.com/itm/304148727288?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0&ssspo=6hPdK0vgQOK&sssrc=4429486&ssuid=H4hCb3nAQpy&var=&widget_ver=artemis&media=COPY) lists the fork axle to crown length as 368mm. To answer your question about the acceptable variance here, I feel that +/-5mm either way would not especially change the ride characteristics. A 44 to 47 mm rake would also ride with imperceptible change in the handling.

Overall, if you stick with the options/listings for forks specific to Specialized Roubaix from the mid 2000's (given the other specs of rim brake, open dropouts at 100mm spacing, straight steer tube with adequate length) you'll be dealing with a like for like replacement.